# JTable isn't updating when adding to Arraylist?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, tablemodel

Ok so I currently have a array list constructed as

```
static List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
```

with values like this

```
    {["ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Vaccine Type", "Vaccination Date", "Vaccine Location"]
["12345", "Doe", "John", "Pfizer", "10/30/2020", "Argentina"]
["54321", "Adam", "Marceline", "Pfizer", "11/19/2020", "Russia"]}
```

I want to display this into a JTable in a GUI when a button is pressed, which works fine.

```
private void initialize(){


    btnLoadData = new JButton("Load Data");
    btnLoadData.addActionListener(this);
    btnLoadData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                    String[] header = {"ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Vaccine Type", "Vaccination Date", "Vaccine Location" };
                    String[][] tempTable = new String[lines.size()][]; 
                    int i = 0;
                    for (List<String> next : lines) {
                        tempTable[i++] = next.toArray(new String[next.size()]); // return Object[][]
                }
            JTable EndTable = new JTable(tempTable,header);
            EndTable.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300);
            panel_2.add(new JScrollPane(EndTable));
            
        }
        });
```

}

However when I try to add an extra row into the Arraylist and then press the button again, the JTable is not updated(at the bottom of the Table in the gui).

```
btnSubmit_3 = new JButton("Submit");
btnSubmit_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String id = textField_1.getText();
            String Lname = textField_2.getText();
            String Fname = textField_3.getText();
            String Vtype = textField_4.getText();
            String Vdate = textField_5.getText();
            String Loc = textField_6.getText();
            List<String> new_row = Arrays.asList(id, Lname, Fname, Vtype, Vdate, Loc);
            lines.add(new_row);
            }
            textField_1.setText("");
            textField_2.setText("");
            textField_3.setText("");
            textField_4.setText("");
            textField_5.setText("");
            textField_6.setText("");
            
            
            
        }
    });
    panel_3.add(btnSubmit_3);
```

I know it does add to the array list because I printed the array list out and there is an extra row there with the user values. But it seems that the JTable is set in stone in the GUI whenever I try to press the button again.

Comment: Among other things, you add elements to an ArrayList while your table data is backed up by a two-dimensional array of Strings, why should it update?

Comment: BTW: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Is `panel_2` removing the old JTable at some point? maybe you are adding it but the old one is still on top... also,  please, rename your variables to mean something, your future self will be grateful. Also, follow Java conventions (lowercase for variables), so instead of Fnane or Lname use firstName and lastName, and instead of   `textField_2` you can name it `lastNameTextField` it's better :).

Comment: @Rocco I'm confident it does update since when I print out the arraylist it has the new elements.

Comment: *when I print out the arraylist it has the new elements.* - the data in the ArrayList is irrelevant. A JTable stores the data in a TableModel. When you first create the JTable, the data is copied from the ArrayList to the TableModel.  If you want to change the data displayed, then you need to update data in the TableModel (not in the ArrayList). This is usually done by invoking the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: @sev.in your code, when you create the JTable, you copy the data from the arraylist, to a new structure: an 2-dimensional array of strings, so there is no link between the Jtable and the original arraylist. As already said, if you want a JTable backed up by an ArrayList you have to create a TableModel using that arraylist and notify changes to the TableModel, please have look at the linked documentation